# What causes ConcurrentHashMap to be resized

Tags: java, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

I believe that a ConcurrentHashMap [is resized here](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/internal/util/collection/ConcurrentHashMapV8.java#L1830-L1831).

I would have expected that a ConcurrentHashMap is resized when the load factor reaches a certain threshold.

However I don't see how the resizing done from the `addCount` method has anything to do with the load factor.

What are the criterias for resizing a ConcurrentHashMap? Is the load factor one of them?

Answer (score 3):

From javadoc of [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

> The table is resized when occupancy exceeds a percentage
>     threshold (nominally, 0.75, but see below).
>
> The table is dynamically expanded when there are too many
>     collisions (i.e., keys that have distinct hash codes but fall into
>     the same slot modulo the table size), with the expected average
>     effect of maintaining roughly two bins per mapping (corresponding
>     to a 0.75 load factor threshold for resizing). There may be much
>     variance around this average as mappings are added and removed, but
>     overall, this maintains a commonly accepted time/space tradeoff for
>     hash tables.  However, resizing this or any other kind of hash
>     table may be a relatively slow operation. When possible, it is a
>     good idea to provide a size estimate as an optional {@code
>     initialCapacity} constructor argument. An additional optional
>     {@code loadFactor} constructor argument provides a further means of
>     customizing initial table capacity by specifying the table density
>     to be used in calculating the amount of space to allocate for the
>     given number of elements.  Also, for compatibility with previous
>     versions of this class, constructors may optionally specify an
>     expected {@code concurrencyLevel} as an additional hint for
>     internal sizing.